# При создании urls.py в PyCharm не подсвечивается синтексис и не распознает как питоновский документ

Tags: python, pycharm

При создании urls.py в PyCharm не подсвечивается синтексис и не распознает как питоновский документ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В `File/Settings` поищите ассоциации файлов, убедитесь что в `Registered patterns` есть `py`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GWOSv6G
Вроде тут всё в порядке, глянь..

Comment: @Astraithios, а тут как дела https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFDu5.png?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yEbFLwh
Тоже нормально(

Comment: @Astraithios, а формат файла urls точно на английском? Мб там не py, а ру

Comment: Судя по иконке у этого файла "Text" file type - идем в "File Types | Text" и убираем `urls.py` из "Registered patterns".

Comment: где вообще найти Registered patterns?